# How to get check status for check box in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have a check box as follow.

```
<input id='showDeletedQuestionsId' name='showDeletedQuestions' type='checkbox' style='margin-right: 3px' />""
```

I want to know if it is checked in jquery. The code is:

```
    var showDeletedCheckbox = $('#showDeletedQuestions').is(':checked');
```

However, I notice that it always returns false even if check box is checked. I'd like to know how to get the check status in jquery.

Comment: can you show entire code?

Comment: yes because your code should work fine

Comment: Try `var showDeletedCheckbox = $('#showDeletedQuestionsId').is(':checked');`

Comment: `showDeletedQuestionsId` and `showDeletedQuestions` not matching

Comment: try sample http://jsfiddle.net/oh0240oq/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input id='showDeletedQuestionsId' name='showDeletedQuestions' type='checkbox' style='margin-right: 3px' />
```

js

```
var showDeletedCheckbox = $('#showDeletedQuestions').is(':checked');
```

your id are not matching match them and it will work

```
$('#showDeletedQuestionsId').change(function () {
    var showDeletedCheckbox = $('#showDeletedQuestionsId').is(':checked');

    if (showDeletedCheckbox) {
        alert('checked')
    } else {
        alert('not checked')
    }
})
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oh0240oq/)

Comment: i am just showing that his code works just fine the problem was that his id is not matching

Answer (score 3):

You are not using ID correctly, `showDeletedQuestionsId` is defined and `showDeletedQuestions` is used

use

```
var showDeletedCheckbox = $('#showDeletedQuestionsId').is(':checked');
```

As an alternative you can use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
var showDeletedCheckbox = $('#showDeletedQuestionsId').prop('checked');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in your code. 
"#" selector is used for Id field only. but you have used "name" attribute in selection. Modify your code as below, it will work..

```
var showDeletedCheckbox = $('#showDeletedQuestionsId').is(':checked');
```

For reference check [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_id.asp)